# Java3D object exported as BufferedImage

Tags: bufferedimage, java-3d

-- may be this query has been on circuit before but I can't find an answer anywhere. --

I have designed a Java3D object which is composed of different shapes, with different colors and lightning effects. Now I like to export this object as BufferedImage. Is there any way to do it. please share your thoughts.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it sounds like you want to take a screenshot of the current 3D scene?  If so, you might want to look at the java.awt.Robot class, something like the following:

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // Capture the screen shot of the area of the screen defined by the rectangle
        BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(100,100));
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:/imageTest.jpg"));
```

source: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-capture-screenshot.html

Comment: Well actually I want to render my Java3D drawing to BufferedImage. so that I can use this image elsewhere.